# Exact Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

How can I solve this in Mathematica ?

Comment: Just check the document of `DSolve`.

Comment: Please show your code. where does your solution come from?

Comment: Your solution is not quite correct. Should be `-Cos[x]^2 + (1 - x^2) y[x]^2+c==0`. In other words, when you write cos^2*x, it is not clear what do you mean. Use Mathematica syntax or at least proper mathematical notations $\left(1-x^2\right) y(x)^2-\cos ^2(x)+c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DSolve` evaluates two solutions

```
sol = DSolve [y'[x] == (x y[x]^2 - Cos[x] Sin[x])/(y[x] ( 1 - x^2)), y, x]
(*{{y -> Function[{x}, -(Sqrt[C[1] - Cos[x]^2]/Sqrt[-1 + x^2])]}, 
{y ->Function[{x}, Sqrt[C[1] - Cos[x]^2]/Sqrt[-1 + x^2]]}}*)

y'[x] == (x y[x]^2 - Cos[x] Sin[x])/(y[x] ( 1 - x^2)) /.sol // Simplify
```

OP's solution

```
-Cos[x]^2/2 - x^2 y[x]^2/2 + y[x]^2/c + c  /. sol
(*{c - Cos[x]^2/2 + (C[1] - Cos[x]^2)/(c (-1 + x^2)) - (x^2 (C[1] - Cos[x]^2))/(2 (-1 + x^2))
,c - Cos[x]^2/2 + (C[1] - Cos[x]^2)/(c (-1 + x^2)) - (x^2 (C[1] - Cos[x]^2))/(2 (-1 + x^2))}*)
```

isn't correct!

Comment: With `Simplify[-Cos[x]^2 + (1 - x^2) y[x]^2 /. sol]` one can check that OPs solution is correct (almost :) )

Comment: OPs solution is different,  contains a parameter `c`

Comment: Apart from some confused notations in the OP, it seems both solutions coincide. Your solution also contains a constant.

Comment: Agreed, but your example doesn't contain a constant

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your point. I am not solving, I am suggesting how to use *your* solution to verify the OP's solution. That was the main question, I guess. I would be willing to upvote your solution, because you have invested some time to type everything,  but I cannot do so, because you do not provide an answer to the main question `Is this correct?`. Moreover, I wonder, if we should answer such poorly formulated questions here.

Comment: @yarchik See my modified answer.

Comment: My apologies for the poorly formatted question. I wasn't sure how to write this question in Mathematica, so I should have simply asked, how? I was looking to confirm my manually worked out solution but there's other sources of assistance for that. I'll be sure to bring some code to the table if I'm to seek help again. Thank you for your time and assistance.